# how to rank web url based on certain keywords on vertex ai search engine

Tags: vertex-ai-search

I want to see some of web URL on top based on keyword search on vertex AI search App bar such that if am typing AI in search bar then specific URL like "https://www.ibm.com/topics/artificial-intelligence" preferred by me comes on top then rest of search results can come after that.

I didn't find any functionality on vertex search and conversation platform to rank the URL based on some keyword given in search.